# Determine the expression for the maximum value of a cuboid

Tags: geometry, derivatives

A box is in the shape of a cuboi has a square as its bottom. The side of the square is $x$ cm. The box's volume is $y$ cm$^2$.

A friend says to you: "If the sum of one side of the bottom area and the box's height is $a$, the expression for the maximum value is $4a^3/27$. Determine whether or not this is true.

What I know:

$y = x^2h$

$a = x+h$

$y = ax$

After this I'm completely lost. I know how to determine the maximum value *if* I know the height, but when all variables are unknown I'm simply too uncreative to find a solution to this problem. I'm sorry if it seems like I'm only begging for an answer.

The solution should (according to my book) be: Yes, it's true. $x = 2a/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use your 2 first equations (about the third one, I can't see what you mean...).

Let's write first the volume $y$ in terms of $x$ and $a$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
y = x^2h\\
a = x + h
\end{cases} \implies y = x^2(a-x) = ax^2 - x^3.
\end{equation}

We must just find the maximum value of $y$ with respect to $x$. That means to equal the $dy/dx=0$ and prove that it's a maximum by seeing that $d^2y/dx^2$ evaluated at the point we found is lower than $0$.

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2ax - 3x^2 = x(2a - 3x)
\end{equation}
will be $0$ if, and only if, $x=0$ or $x = 2a/3$. When $x=0$, $y=0$. So, $x=0$ doesn't seem to be the value that we want. When $x = 2a/3$,
\begin{equation}
y = (2a/3)^2·(a - 2a/3) = \frac{4}{9}a^2\frac{1}{3}a = \frac{4a^3}{27}.
\end{equation}
It suffices to show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ evaluated at $x = 2a/3$ is lower than $0$ to prove the statement.

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right|_{x = 2a/3} = \left.2a - 6x\right|_{x = 2a/3} = -2a < 0
\end{equation}